# field cannot be null but specified

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hello i have a problem that i think it's easy for someone but i'm not you're i'm human :)
So my problem is this :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'quantity' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into products (title, price, description, subtitle, token, type_of_product, category, updated_at, created_at) values (bonjour, 20, bonjour, bonjour, MWnBp|z|/#o"/G, 1, hello, 2020-04-03 20:33:38, 2020-04-03 20:33:38))
```

I have specified the field in my blade file :

```
 <input name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity Of Your Product">
```

My Controller :

```
//Create Product In Database with Mysql eloquent
public function pushFormProduct(Request $request){
    $inputs = $request->all();
    $product = new Product();
    $product->title = $inputs['title'];
    $product->subtitle = $inputs['subtitle'];
    $product->description = $inputs['description'];
    $product->quantity = $inputs['quantity'];
    $product->price = $inputs['price'];
    $product->type_of_product = $inputs['type_of_product'];
    $product->category = $inputs['category'];
    $product->create($inputs);
    return redirect(route('admin.view.product'));
}
```

And if i :

```
dd($inputs['quantity'])
```

That return me the exact quantity of the product.

But if i push all field to create a new products i have the error ( i declared it in the upside :))

So i don't know who, and why i have this bug, because the field have the good value.
Any purpose ?

Comment: ok it's my fillable model, i have not specified the field quantity to be a fillable value that my error !

Comment: I was going to say that. Anyway glad you nipped it in the bud

Comment: None of those `$product->title`, `$product->subtitle` settings are doing anything... You're passing `$inputs` to the `create()` method, so you can literally remove all of those, or change `$product->create($inputs);` to `$product->save();` You're mixing methods here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the field `quantity` as fillable

Comment: that it's :) i have posted fo nothing orrrr :)

Comment: Happens more often than you think. You finish and post the question and then you realize the answer ^_^

Comment: exactly 10 minutes i'm on the code to try to dd in my mass assignement but that not work because my fillable quantity does not exist :)

Comment: i have try but 6 min to wait

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a couple of things wrong:

1. If you want to use the create method, you need to have quantity as fillable in your model's $fillable protected property array. e.g.

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'subtitle',
        'description',
        'quantity', // <---
        'price',
        'type_of_product',
        'category',
    ];
}
```

You're using create incorrectly. You should call `Product::create($request->all())` instead. Or:

```
Product::create(
    $request->only([
        'title',
        'subtitle',
        'description',
        'quantity',
        'price',
        'type_of_product',
        'category',
    ])
);
```

2. If using a new instance of the model e.g. `$product = new Product;` (which allows you to to bypass fillable if you set e.g. `$product->quantity = 123;` then you need to call `$product->save();` afterwards.

Comment: Thank for the answer i will be better on my code, and you give me the best gift for crud in laravel, Thank you i will try this in my next crud or in my refactoring code.